# Leitura de String

Tags: c, array, string

```
char nome[100], endereco[100], sexo[100];

   printf("Digite seu nome: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", nome); 

   printf("Digite seu endereço: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", endereco);

   printf("Qual seu sexo: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", sexo);
```

Esta tendo erro na leitura de Strings endereco e sexo, quando leio o nome na entrada de nome (EX: Lucas Martins), roda normalmente, mas quando chega para lê endereco em seguida não permite coloca o endereco, dar erro ! Por qual motivo o erro ?

Comment: testa usar a palavra endereço sem o ç.

Comment: Se quiser pode responder sua propria perguna, pode ser util para outros que tenham a mesma duvida.

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui.

Fiz assim

```
char nome[100], endereco[100], sexo[100];

printf("Digite seu nome: "); 
scanf(" %[^\n]", nome);

printf("Digite seu endereço: "); 
scanf(" %[^\n]", endereco);

printf("Qual seu sexo: "); 
scanf(" %[^\n]", sexo);
```

Tirei o S pois os colchetes já deixam explícito que é a leitura de uma string, e só afastei o % da primeira " fazendo com que fosse permitido a leitura da próxima entrada!

Answer (score 0):

Sei que a função scanf trabalha com ponteiros, e um dos argumentos dela seria passar a referência'&', ou seja o endereço de memória onde esta separada para as suas variáveis do programa.
**Ex.: char nome,   scanf('Digite algo:',&nome);Acredito quando se trabalha com vetores você tera que fazer o 'incremento do índice', tipo a[0],a[1],a[2]...,**
Se você quiser não se preocupar com isto tera que trabalhar com ponteiros, pois toda a manipulação de 'endereços' o compilador já enxertou no código quando se usa ponteiros, exemplo:
 **#define buffer 100; char nome[buffer]; char *str; str=nome; e finalmente scanf("texto para string vetor",str);** 
Sabe por que tudo isto:::
Porque o ponteiro é um 'ponteiro', um apontador para um endereço de memória da variavel.